# ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition when trying to use if elseif

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting 'ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition'

```
procedure create_dates_testing  (dummy_variable varchar2 default 
 to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')) is

begin
DECLARE
day_of_month varchar2(255) := extract(day from sysdate);
today varchar2(255) := to_char(sysdate, 'DAY');
start_date date;
next_start_date date;

BEGIN
IF today='SUNDAY' THEN
-- Select yesterday
start_date      := trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day;
next_start_date := trunc(sysdate);

ELSE IF day_of_month=3 then
-- Select the whole of last month
start_date      := runc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month;
next_start_date := runc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month

END IF;
END;

execute immediate 'drop table new_customers';
execute immediate 'create table new_customers as 
select id, client_name, invoice_date 
from clients table
where transactiondate >= :start_date
and transactiondate <  :next_start_date;';


end;
```

How can I resolve this error? Where am I going wrong? I need to put this procedure in a pl/sql package.

Comment: I'm sure there's plenty wrong here, starting with your use of `RUNC`, which I assume is a typo for `TRUNC`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can't use bind variables here, so you have to concatenate:

```
create or replace procedure create_dates_testing 
    ( dummy_variable varchar2 default to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') )
as
    day_of_month varchar2(255) := extract(day from sysdate);
    today varchar2(255) := to_char(sysdate +1, 'fmDAY', 'nls_date_language = English');
    start_date date;
    next_start_date date;
begin
    if today = 'SUNDAY' then
        -- select yesterday
        start_date      := trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day;
        next_start_date := trunc(sysdate);

    elsif day_of_month = 3 then
        -- select the whole of last month
        start_date      := trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month;
        next_start_date := trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month;
    else
        return;
    end if;

    execute immediate 'drop table new_customers';

    execute immediate 'create table new_customers as 
    select id, client_name, invoice_date 
    from clients table
    where transactiondate >= date '''  || to_char(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') ||
    ''' and transactiondate < date ''' || to_char(next_start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') ||'''';

end create_dates_testing;
```

Presumably there will be some more code to handle the case where it is neither Sunday nor the third of the month, or the `new_customers` table does not exist.

Edit: added `else` condition to end processing if neither of the date conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks, William! I do have some more code but what if this is all I want and just end the if elsif statement. How would I do that?

Comment: `else return;` perhaps?

Comment: Thank-you! I ran the code as is and getting the below error now.ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: I'm guessing one of your dates came out as null. I've added an `else` condition above. Is that where it is in your version? You might also build the string in a variable and print it out first or in an exception handler for easier error diagnosis.

Comment: Hi, i never saw this use of "date + string" before, I usually do a "To_date(string)". Can you point me some documentation of that keyword usage?

Comment: It’s how we write date literals in Oracle. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1

Comment: don't do that. you can bind variables to execute immediate by adding a "using" clause.

Comment: Not for DDL, unfortunately.